# ToOneField filtering with tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I try to filter ressource with OneToField field.

I want have the favorite related of task secure_key given as by this url:
/favorite/api/all/?task__secure_key=sdsd900kljhiu987bbhU

and tastypie return:

```
{"error": "The 'secure_key' field does not allow filtering."}
```

Here are my files:

favorite/api.py

```
class FavoriteRessource(ModelResource):
    task = fields.ToOneField('task.api.TaskResource', attribute='task', full=True)
    user = fields.ToOneField('foruser.api.UserRessource', attribute='user', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Favorite.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'all'
        excludes = ['id']
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        include_resource_uri = False
        authentication = BaseAuthentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        filtering = {
            'task': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }
```

task/api.py

```
class TaskResource(ModelResource):
    city = fields.ToOneField(AppCityRessource, attribute='city', null=True, full=True)
    category = fields.ToOneField(TaskCategoryResource, attribute='category', null=True, full=True)
    user = fields.ToOneField(UserRessource, attribute='user', null=True, full=True)
    skill = fields.ToManyField(SkillRessource, attribute='skill', full=True)

    class Meta:
        #queryset = Task.objects.filter(active=True, admin_active=True, skill_active=True)
        queryset = Task.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'all'
        excludes = ['active', 'admin_active', 'skill_active', 'participant_history']
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
        always_return_data = True
        include_resource_uri = False
        authentication = BaseAuthentication()
        authorization = Authorization()        
        filtering = { 
            'secure_key': ALL,
        }
```

Where is my error?

Comment: Have you tried to add `secure_key` as one of returned fields for TaskResource (beside city, category, user, etc)? If succeed and you don't want `secure_key` as returned field, then remove it via `dehydrate`

Comment: No I don't, because secure_key is a field of the Task model.